# Nodejs lambda function exits after 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, lambda

Below lambda function exit after 30 seconds

Intend is the following function should trigger when ever data is written to fire base db locally the function is working fine for 30 seconds but when i deploy the same in AWs the function just runs and stops(It will not wait until data is coming from fire base db)

'use strict';
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

```
let atlas_connection_uri;
let cachedDb = null;

let firebase = require('firebase');

exports.handler = function(event, context,callback)
{
    // var uri = process.env['MONGODB_ATLAS_CLUSTER_URI'];
    var uri = "mongodb://dshan:1ew10is022@ds139904.mlab.com:39904/vishchatapp";
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    firebase.initializeApp({
        serviceAccount: {},
        databaseURL: "https://harmanconnectedcar-180411.firebaseio.com/"
    });

    var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('events' );
    starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log("*************snapshot*****snapshot*****************")
        console.log (snapshot.val()) ;
        if (atlas_connection_uri != null) {
            processEvent(event, context, callback,snapshot.val());
        }
        else {
            atlas_connection_uri = uri;
            console.log('the Atlas connection string is ' + atlas_connection_uri);
            processEvent(event, context, callback,snapshot.val());
        }
       /* context.succeed();*/
    });


};

function processEvent(event, context, callback,triggerData) {
    console.log('Calling MongoDB Atlas from AWS Lambda with event: ' + JSON.stringify(event));
   }
```

Increased the execution time to maximum one minute in AWS but still not able to get the data from the event in AWS please say how to make the function alive and get the data to db

Comment: `Q: How long can an AWS Lambda function execute?

All calls made to AWS Lambda must complete execution within 300 seconds. The default timeout is 3 seconds, but you can set the timeout to any value between 1 and 300 seconds.` Did you set right properties? https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

Comment: yes that is execution but what if i want ti trigger the function when ever the data comes irrespective of time

Comment: This design seems outside of the viable use cases for Lambda functions.  You need a persistent process somewhere, unless firebase can push a notification with a mechanism more closely resembling a webhook (in which case, use API Gateway to invoke the Lambda).